# I can pass a scope variable into a directive's link function, but not the compile function, angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using ng-repeat and I need to pass a scope variable into a directive's compile function. I know how to do it with the link function, but not the compile function.

My html looks like:

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in chapter.main">
      <block type="item.type"></block>
    </div>
```

Let's say item.type="blah" no matter the item. 
Then this link function works fine

```
app.directive('block', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            scope.$watch(attributes.type, function(value){
                console.log(value); //will output "blah" which is correct
            });

        }
  }
});
```

But I can't do the same with compile?

```
app.directive('block', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(element, attrs, scope) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.type, function(value){
             console.log(value);
         });
      }
  }
});
```

The error I get is "cannot read property $watch of undefined"..

This is how I'd like my directive to look like:

```
app.directive('block', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(element, attrs) {
        element.append('<div ng-include="\'{{type}}-template.html\'"></div>');
        //or element.append('<div ng-include="\'{' + attrs.type + '}-template.html\'"></div>');
        //except the above won't interpret attr.type as a variable, just as the literal string 'item.type'
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Here is an interesting [article](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/) about `compile` and how it works in `Angularjs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compile` function doesn't have `scope` as one it's parameter.

`function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) { ... }`

NOTE: transclude is deprecated in the latest version of Angular.

Is there any reason you don't want to use `link`?

From the DOC

> The compile function deals with transforming the template DOM. Since most directives do not do template transformation, it is not used often. The compile function takes the following arguments:
>
> tElement - template element - The element where the directive has been declared. It is safe to do template transformation on the element and child elements only.
>
> tAttrs - template attributes - Normalized list of attributes declared on this element shared between all directive compile functions.
>
> transclude - [DEPRECATED!] A transclude linking function: function(scope, cloneLinkingFn)

**UPDATE**

To access the scope from inside `compile` function, you need to have either a `preLink` or `postLink` function. In your case, you need only the `postLink` function. So this ...

```
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
    return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) { ... }
},
```

**PROPOSED SOLUTION** Might not be exact but should help you on your way.

**html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="app">
    <block type="item.type"></block>
</div>
```

**JS (Controller + Directive)**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('app', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.item = {
        type: 'someTmpl'
    };
}).directive('block', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            type: '='
        },
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var tmpl;
                tmpl = scope.type + '-template.html';
                
                console.log(tmpl);
                
                element.append('<div ng-include=' + tmpl + '></div>');

                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Hmm, I just wouldn't know how to use link- do you mean something like adding `element.append('<div ng-include="\''+value+'-template.html\'"></div>');` inside the link/ watch function? Because I tried that and got nothing...

Comment: @thatandrey, check the proposed solution above ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I think it's supposed to be `console.log(tmpl)`? And I ended up using `element.append('<div ng-include="\''+scope.type+'-template.html\'"></div>');` because I think there should be an extra set of parenthesis around the file name, otherwise the template wasn't loading, otherwise, it works great, thanks!

Comment: One last thing, I just noticed, the other thing I'd like to do is access other properties in the scope model, like item.content. In the fiddle here, I was able to do it no problem, but a similar binding doesn't seem to work with your solution? http://jsfiddle.net/01h3ne4y/ In that fiddle, I'm still able to access `foo.test` from  the controller

Comment: If you'd like to access the whole item object then bind it to the directive like this `<my-directive item=item></my-directive>`. `item` being `$scope.item` in your controller and then in your directive do `scope: {item: '=item'}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77642/discussion-between-thatandrey-and-dcodesmith).